# How to group list by numbers

Tags: python, list, numpy

Hello i have a list of the sort:

```
lst = [0.0000,0.0542,0.0899,0.7999,0.9999,1.8754]
```

The list keeps going.

Is there any way i can group the by one?
Like for example every value that is between 0 to 1, and 1 to 2 etc.

As Id like to reppresent it on matplotlib of the count of numbers per group.

I tried everything but no success.

Comment: So, do you want  `[0.0000,0.0542,0.0899,0.7999,0.9999]` for group value 1, and `[1.8754] ` for group value 2?

Comment: what do you mean by grouping?

Comment: Sort your list first then `for g, values in itertools.groupby(lst, key=lambda value: int(value)): print(g, list(values))`.

Comment: check out jakevdp's [histograms and binnings](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.05-histograms-and-binnings.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice library named `itertools` which has a function called `groupby` which can help you here. It collects adjacent values in a list together based on a predicate.

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = [0.0000,0.0542,0.0899,0.7999,0.9999,1.8754]
grouped_lst = [list(g) for k,g in groupby(lst, lambda x:int(x))]
```

Output:

```
[[0.0, 0.0542, 0.0899, 0.7999, 0.9999], [1.8754]]
```

`lambda x:int(x)` is the predicate here. `int` will convert your values to an integer i.e remove the decimal point. You can then loop over these 'groups' and convert them to a list using `list(g)`.

Note this method will only work if your list is sorted. Please sort your list beforehand if it may not be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/) and [`numpy_indexed`](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP):

```
import numpy as np
import numpy_indexed as npi

lst = [0.0000,0.0542,0.0899,0.7999,0.9999,1.8754]

npi.group_by(np.trunc(lst), lst)
```

**Output**

```
(array([0., 1.]),
 [array([0.    , 0.0542, 0.0899, 0.7999, 0.9999]), array([1.8754])])
#keys and groups
```

---

You can easily install the library with:

```
> pip install numpy-indexed
```